# Matrix of numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, matrix

I need help with a function in JS that prints a matrix by a given integer N like this:

```
N = 2;
Matrix: 1 2
        2 3
N = 3;
Matrix: 1 2 3
        2 3 4
        3 4 5
```

I need to make it with 2 loops but I can't figure out how

```
function solve(args) {
  var n = args[0];  
}
```

PS: Sorry for inserting the matrixes into JS code but that way I could visualise the result.

Comment: print per console.log() or as a string with linebreaks or as document.createElement?

Comment: You have 2 answer from 2 different need, on print using console, the second print in html page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the logic

```js
function paintMatrix(n) {

    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      var result = "";
      for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result += (i + j - 1);
      }
      console.log(result);
    }
}

paintMatrix(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider  the following short solution using ES6 `Array.fill`, `Array.map` and `Array.join` functions:

```
function printMatrix(size){
     if (size <= 1) console.log(size); // if 0/1 was passed in - outputs it as is
     var len = size, count = Array(size).fill(null), matrix = "";

     while (len--) matrix = count.map((v, k) => len + 1 + k).join(" ") +"\n" + matrix;
     console.log(matrix);
 }

 console.log("3 dimensional matrix:");
 printMatrix(3);

 console.log("5 dimensional matrix:");
 printMatrix(5);
```

The output:

```
3 dimensional matrix:
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5

5 dimensional matrix:
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doMatrix(n){
    var i=0;
    var ret = "";
    for(var x=1+i; x<=n; x++){
      for(var l=x; l<n+x; l++)
           ret += l;
       ret += "\n";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rksLjjzf/

Answer (score 0):

```
function martix(number) {
    for (var y = 1; y<=number; y++) {
        for (var x = y; x<number + y; x++) {
            var n = x;
            print(n + '&nspb;');
        }
        print('<br />');
    }
}
```

where "print" would be a function which writes the given input to "somewhere"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function createMatrix(len){
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    result.push(new Array(len).fill(i).map(function(item, index){ return item + index}));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(createMatrix(3))
```