# how to create nxn matrix/array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array or matrix with non-fixed number of rows like

```
var matrix=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix of numbers javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016201/matrix-of-numbers-javascript)

Comment: What is stopping you from just doing it as you already wrote it? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/966234/1063673) for multi dimensional array access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can alse use the code like:

```
function matrix(m, n) {
    var result = []
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result.push(new Array(m).fill(0))
    }
    return result
}
console.log(matrix(2,5))
```

Comment: is it possible to get same result without using .fill() ?

Answer (score 15):

An ES6 solution using **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** and **[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)** methods.

```js
function matrix(m, n) {
  return Array.from({
    // generate array of length m
    length: m
    // inside map function generate array of size n
    // and fill it with `0`
  }, () => new Array(n).fill(0));
};

console.log(matrix(3,2));
```

Answer (score 3):

### For enhanced readability

```
const create = (amount) => new Array(amount).fill(0);
const matrix = (rows, cols) => create(cols).map((o, i) => create(rows))

console.log(matrix(2,5))
```

### For less code

```
const matrix = (rows, cols) => new Array(cols).fill(0).map((o, i) => new Array(rows).fill(0))

console.log(matrix(2,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following ES5 code:

```
var a = "123456".split("");
var b = "abcd".split("");
var A = a.length;
var B = b.length;

var t= new Array(A*B);
for (i=0;i<t.length;i++) {t[i]=[[],[]];} 

t.map(function(x,y) {
   x[0] = a[parseInt(y/B)];
   x[1] = b[parseInt(y%B)];
  });    
t;
```

It returns a 2d array and obviously your input doesn't have to be strings.

For some amazing answers in ES6 and other languages check out my question in stack exchange, [ppcg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125104/cartesian-product-of-two-lists).

Answer (score 0):

```
function createArray(row, col) {
  let matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    matrix.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      matrix[i].push([]);
    }
  }
  console.log(matrix);
}

createArray(2, 3);
```

OUTPUT:-
`[ [ [], [], [] ], [ [], [], [] ] ]`

note: if you want to get array with values, like `[ [ [1], [1], [1] ], [ [1], [1], [1] ] ]` then replace 6th line of code with `matrix[i].push([1]);`

Answer (score -1):

Can be done like this:

```
Array(n).fill(Array(m).fill(0))
```

where

```
n - number of rows
m - number of columns
```

Comment: Each row will reference the same object! That's probably isn't desired

Comment: right, see what happens if you declare e.g. 5x5 matrix this way and then set a[2][3] = 1